# Start program when server reboots without root access

Tags: startup, users

I googled and all solutions involve root access. Even user jobs in `~/.init` require you to first edit some system settings file as root. Is there a userspace solution?

Comment: Have you tried `@reboot /path/to/program` in your crontab ? You can edit crontab with `crontab -e`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign new `cron` task, add `@reboot` parameter to your script/command make it executed once on bootup.

```
crontab -e
```

Then, add the `cron` command.

```
@reboot /path/to/your/program
```

Where `/path/to/your/program` is your desired script/command.

**Note that this does not required root access**